# After Change Server Model not work in yii

Tags: php, model-view-controller, model, yii2

I'm new in `yii2`. I'm writing a web site using `yii` in windows `xampp` server.
After completing the website, I want to upload it in `apache` server and using the code but I faced the below error message:

```
PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException

Class 'app\models\event' not found
```

I try to recreate one the model using `gii` and it worked. Should I replace all models or did I do something wrong?

Comment: have you delete the runtime  directory?

Comment: no i didn't change any thing . i should remove runtime directory ?

Comment: Yes .. i have posted  an aswer ..

Comment: @Rome check if this is not a case-sensitive problem with file names. Remember that if your class is named `MyClass` and its file is named `myclass.php` it's not a problem on Windows but it's a huge one on Linux.

Comment: Check note that @Bizley mentioned + dump autoload for static searching of classes with `composer dumpautoload`.

Comment: @Bizley Excellent Point .. I Completely Forgot About Case Sensitivity ,Thanks Alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I Remove runtime directory and fix the case sensitive mismatch my problem has been solved
Thanks A lot For Help